# Attempting to stop AJAX on undo link

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I am trying to delete a list with undo operation. When a customer deletes the list, I am trying to take him from list detail page (current page) to lists page (all list) where I will be having a link called undo for 4 sec. once the user clicks undo link list will restore and the user will stay on the same page.but my issue is deleting ajax call getting calling even I click on the undo link.I need to stop the scheduled ajax (10 sec) when a user clicks on the undo link.

```js
var isUndoClicked = false;

deleteProductList : function() {
  var listCode = 123; //some value.
  if (listCode) {
    $('#listDeleteUndoLink').click(function() {
      this.isUndoClicked = true;
      $('#' + listCode).show();
    });
    if (!this.isUndoClicked) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        this.xhr = $.ajax({
          url: "/lists/deleteListAjax/" + listCode,
          type: "get",
        }).done(function(data) {});
      }, 10000);
    }
  }
},
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="listDeleteUndoLink">
```

Comment: Did you try `this.xhr.abort()` ?

Comment: clearTimeout(timer) getting the job done.

Answer (score 2):

add an on click listener and "return false" to exit the function, and use clearTimeout(var) to stop the timer.

```js
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    // do stuff
}, 1000);

$('#listDeleteUndoLink').on('click', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="listDeleteUndoLink">
```